# Calling $http promise inside controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Thanks in advance for the help...

I have a controller I'm using to call an API to send a password reset link. I have abstracted the actual $http call off into a service to keep the controller thin. Originally I was doing something like this:

```
angular.module('module')
    .service('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function($http) {
   $http(request).then(function() {
       return {}; //return some object using response 
}]);
```

I felt like this would be the best approach as it would keep the controller as thin as possible and kept all service related actions separate. My problem with this was that returning from within the promise never actually returned me anything. I had to actually return the $http service call to get the promise. The only way I was able to make all of this work was if I called .then from within the controller.

```
//controller
angular.module('module')
    .controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', ['forgotPasswordService', function(forgotPasswordService) {
forgotPasswordService.forgotPassword(emailAddress).then(function() {
        //do stuff
    }
}]);
//service
angular.module('module')
    .service('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function($http){
    this.forgotPassword = function(emailAddress) {
        return $http(request);
    };
}]);
```

This just feels a little wrong to me because the controller now depends on receiving a promise back from the service. I may just be overthinking this but I would like a second opinion.

Is this considered acceptable/good practice? Is there an alternative to this which would allow me to achieve the encapsulation I'm looking for?

Thanks again.

Comment: Calling .then in your controller is completely acceptable and the way I'd implement your controller.

Comment: agree with @StevenWexler that is an acceptable and good way of handling the promise. the benefit to this is that it's not so abstract when you or another developer is reading your controller code and you have the data available to your controller without another variable assignment /  calling another variable.

Comment: I think sending a promise back to the controller is not a bad idea. In a sense the controller knows what it is expecting from the http call as opposed to the service. The service has to deal with invoking whatever is asked by the controller and returning a promise, so that the controller would deal with success or failure of the call at a later stage. If we decide that we give this power of handling the result to the service then how is it going to send the response back to the controller? Things would get complicated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've interfaced with the `$http` from the controller in two slightly different ways.

Like you it felt wrong returning the `$http` from the service and interfacing with it.

So first I created services and passed in a success method and an error method (callbacks).

```
// Service
  angular.module('module')
    .service('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function($http) {

        function sendForgotPasswordEmail(emailAddress, success, error){
            $http.post('/api/v1/resetpassword', {emailAddress:emailAddress})
            .then(success, error);
        }

      return {
        sendForgotPasswordEmail: sendForgotPasswordEmail
      }
}]);

// Controller
angular.module('module')
    .controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', ['forgotPasswordService', function(forgotPasswordService) {

        forgotPasswordService.sendForgotPasswordEmail(emailAddress, 
        function(response){ //success
          // notify user of success
        },
        function(response){ // error
          // notify user of error
        });
}]);
```

This worked great. I created an large application this way, but as I started on my second large angular project I wondered why I was hiding the `$http`'s promise?

By passing back the promise, I can use other libraries that support promises. With my first approach I can't leverage other libraries promise support.

**Passing back the $http promise**

```
// Service
  angular.module('module')
    .service('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function($http) {

        function sendForgotPasswordEmail(emailAddress){
          return $http.post('/api/v1/resetpassword', {emailAddress:emailAddress});
        }

      return {
        sendForgotPasswordEmail: sendForgotPasswordEmail
      }
}]);

// Controller
angular.module('module')
    .controller('forgotPasswordCtrl', ['forgotPasswordService', function(forgotPasswordService) {

        forgotPasswordService.sendForgotPasswordEmail(emailAddress)
        .then(
              function(response){ //success
                // notify user of success
              },
              function(response){ // error
                // notify user of error
              });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2):

I deleted my original answer, and I feel like a dork for stating that you could do it the other way.  When I went back and checked my original code back when I first started angular, I found that I was calling `then()` twice in my application - once in my service where I returned the data, and once in my controller because calling `$http(request).then()` returns a **promise**.

The fact is, you're dealing with an asynchronous call.  Suppose in your controller, you wanted to do this:

```
$scope.foo = myService.getFoo(); // No then()
```

The XmlHttpRequest inside the $http in `getFoo()` is an asynchronous call, meaning that it calls it and moves on.  The synchronous option is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request).  It's **bad practice** to make a blocking synchronous HTTP call because it will seize up your UI. This means you should use a callback when the data is ready, and the promise API is made just for that.

If you absolutely do not want to use the `then()` in your controller, I suppose you could probably pass your scope binding parameters to your service and let your service update them in your then call.  I haven't tried this, and because it's asynchronous, I'm not sure if angular will know to call a `digest()` so you may need to call a `$scope.$apply()` if the values don't update.  I don't like this, because I think the *control* of the values in the scope should be handled by the *controller* and not the service, but again - it's your personal preference.

Sorry for leading you astray with my initial answer - I ran into the same question you had, but when I looked back - I saw I used a silly solution.

-- Relevant statements in original answer --

Consider the following:

Where do you want your error handling for the call and who needs to know about it?

Do you need to handle specific failures in a particular controller or can they all be grouped together to one error handler? For some apps, I like to display the errors in a particular place rather than in a general modal dialog, but it's acceptable to create a service to handle all errors and pop them up for the user.

Where do you want to handle your progress/busy indicator?

If you have an interceptor wired up for all http calls and broadcasting an event to show/hide the busy indicator, then you don't need to worry about handling the promise in the controller. However some directives will use the promise to show a busy indicator which requires you to bind it to the scope in the controller.

To me, the decision is determined by the requirements and by personal choice.

Comment: I appreciate the answer anyhow. I'm trying to all but eradicate usage of $scope because I think it can get dirty when adding properties and functions to it. I'm opting for the controllerAs approach for that. I'll still use $scope sparingly though, but I'm not going to be adding properties and functions to it if it can be avoided. Thanks again though!

Comment: ControllerAs is the way to go!  It solves the hierarchical mayhem issue (e.g. `{{ $parent.$parent.$parent.foo }}`).  Angular2 won't be using it so it's good practice.  I used $scope my snippet because it was clearer than `vm.foo = myService.getFoo();`.  Not everyone would know the `var vm = this;` convention.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a callback like so:

```
angular.module('module')
    .service('forgotPasswordService', ['$http', function($http) {
   var recovery = function(request, callback) {
       $http(request).then(function(response) {
           callback(response);
       })
   }
   return { recovery: recovery }
}]);
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
forgotPasswordService.recovery('http://...', function(response){
     console.log(response);
})
```